# Using CORS and CSRF together in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, cors, ionic-framework, csrf

I'm developing a android app using [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) based in a AngularJS web site I developed using [Jhipster](https://jhipster.github.io/). As I already have server code running in my web application, I've choose Ionic to work as UI and call server when needed, but I'm having some issues in my development enviroment.

1. As I run my application using Ionic serve, I need use [CORS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to make requests to server.
2. My web application was developed using CSRF token with Spring Security

I'm using [Apache CORS filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) configured this way:

```
private void initCORSFilter(ServletContext servletContext, EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps) {
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("cors", new CorsFilter());
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("cors.allowed.origins", "http://localhost:3000");
    parameters.put("cors.allowed.headers", "x-auth-token, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, cache-control, x-csrf-token, Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    parameters.put("cors.allowed.methods", "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE");
    parameters.put("cors.exposed.headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    parameters.put("cors.support.credentials", "true");
    corsFilter.setInitParameters(parameters);
    corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/*");
}
```

then I used [angular-csrf-cross-domain](https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-csrf-cross-domain) plugin to help with cross domain csrf requests:

```
.config(function ($urlRouterProvider,csrfCDProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    //enable CSRF
    csrfCDProvider.setHeaderName('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
    csrfCDProvider.setCookieName('CSRF-TOKEN');
});
```

Then I try send a post request to my local server:

```
angular.module('consamiApp')
.factory('Register', function ($resource) {
    //globalURL is https://localhost:8080
    return $resource(globalURL+'api/register', {}, {
    });
});
.
.
.
createAccount: function (account, callback) {
    var cb = callback || angular.noop;

    return Register.save(account,
        function () {
            return cb(account);
        },
        function (err) {
            this.logout();
            return cb(err);
    }.bind(this)).$promise;
}
```

However I'm getting this message in firefox console:

> Cross-origin locked request: The same origin policy (Same Origin Policy) prevents reading the remote resource in https://localhost:8080/api/register. (Reason: CORS heading 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is not present)

**NEW INFORMATION**

AngularJs make 2 CORS requests to the server when I submit the form I'm testing: OPTIONS and POST, the results of the requests are 200 OK and 403 Forbidden. These are the headers of the 2 requests and responses:

OPTIONS Request headers:

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

OPTIONS Answer headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 22:07:58 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=485A653AEAC8B8756DD3057BBF7FB862; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
CSRF-TOKEN=e8b3396c-63b2-47bf-9ad6-c1454628eb3b; Path=/
X-Application-Context: application:dev:8080
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: origin,access-control-request-headers,x-requested-with,x-csrf-token,content-type,access-control-request-method,cache-control,x-auth-token,accept
access-control-allow-methods: POST
access-control-max-age: 1800
```

POST Request Headers:

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Content-Length: 109
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.123103160.1428358695; connect.sid=s%3AwD4KP4WBfhGO0JpFND3LpCzW.augts9fos9NMaZw%2B7XrNuilgaM8ocwSxaEUeDlIaVJ4; JSESSIONID=93200F4F4AFCEB28F10B130841808621
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

POST Answer Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 22:07:58 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Is there something I didn't noticed? The [Ionic's official blog](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) says I should not worry about CORS issue when deploying the app, however at least for tests, I really need solve this problems. Could you give me any options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I edited the question and saw the OPTIONS response header with HttpOnly clause, I started believe that the problem was with self signed certificate I'm using in development enviroment.

> Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=485A653AEAC8B8756DD3057BBF7FB862; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

So I've decided disable https protocol in the web server and it worked correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How to set this JSESSIONID

Answer (score 5):

Have you installed and configured [cordova plugin whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) that is mandatory for CORS query since Cordova 5.0.0

**install it :**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

**configure config.xml**

You can keep your current setup with * or change for more restrictive rules

**add a html policy**
on index.html, you shall add a Policy also.
To authorise everything, here it is :

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
 style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
 'unsafe-eval'"
```

To verify that you have properly the plugin installed, check it into your cordova plugins with the following command:

```
cordova plugins
```

You shall see the cordova-plugin-whitelist in it.

Secondly, you may need to add `withCredentials` to your $`http` (and therefore $resource) queries :

```
  .config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    });
```

Comment: if you did not use ionic to generate the project then @aofevre is most likely correct. If you use ionic they now include the plugin into the project.

Comment: where have you seen that ionic wrap the cordova plugin whitelist ? So far, I see that it shal lbe installed manually (http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/cordova-whitelist).

Comment: I have add the cordova command into response to verify that the whitelist plugin is well installed; but I still can't find any indication if ionic includes already this plugin;)

Comment: if you run ionic start test blank (starting a new blank ionic project) look in the plugins folder! BAM! the whitelist plugin is there

Comment: As @JessPatton told, the whitelist plugin is installed by default in Ionic. I added the meta tag, but the result is the same. I've added the headers of the requests in the question, perhaps there is something I'm not seeing.

Comment: So you should have <access origin="*"/> in config.xml + META policy setted up into your index.html; right ?

Answer (score 1):

The CORS spec is all-or-nothing. It only supports *, null or the exact domain: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header

I don't think you can specify port numbers as its value.

Comment: I've escaped : character for port, according with [angularjs $resource doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)